# Extending dget to a column in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Given the following formula:

```
=dget(Sheet2!$A:$C,Sheet2!B$1,{"USER ID";$A2})
```

Is there a way to alter this formula so that it fills all the values in a column? I've tried with `arrayformula`, changing `$A2` for `$A2:$A`, but I can't make it work .

Comment: I have no problem extending this formula exactly as written. Can you post a sample spreadsheet where it does not work for you?

Comment: You mean that, using `=ARRAYFORMULA(DGET(Sheet2!$A:$C,Sheet2!B$1,{"USER ID";$A2:A})`, a whole column of data fills in, or that you can copy and paste it in other cells as is? The data I have can't be shared, but I'll make up another sheet and I'll post it. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't use arrayformula; just entered what you have and [auto-filled](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75509?hl=en) the rest of column.

Comment: I see... I'm trying to figure out if the auto-fill can be avoided some formula, so as to simplify maintenance... if this option exists at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) instead of `DGET`; it has simpler syntax and works with `ARRAYFORMULA`. Example:

*Sheet2 columns A and B*

```
+---------+-------+
| User Id | Name  |
+---------+-------+
|    4444 | Grace |
|    1111 | Jon   |
|    2222 | Tim   |
+---------+-------+
```

Another sheet has numbers 1111, 2222, 4444, 2222 in cells A2-A5.

Entering in B2 the formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A5,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE))
```

will fill out the table

```
+------+-------+
| 1111 | Jon   |
| 2222 | Tim   |
| 4444 | Grace |
| 2222 | Tim   |
+------+-------+
```

But you probably want `=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE))` to avoid specifying the end row. As written, this will work but will produce a bunch of #N/A errors in empty rows, because `VLOOKUP` fails when given an empty string as a key. These can be suppressed with `IFERROR`: change B2 to

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick question: would it be possible to use `IFERROR` instead of `IF(ISERROR(...`? Is there any difference in doing either of them? Also, can you have multiple parametres using `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: You're right, IFERROR is exactly the thing to use here. Updated.

Comment: No, `VLOOKUP` has only one search key. I assumed this is the case for you since `DGET` requires a unique match, and this is rarely assured when you are  matching multiple fields. If your query is more complex than looking up an entry by an ID column, consider [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343).